# Calcular diferença entre horas no php

Tags: php, time, matemática

Estou tentando mostrar quantas horas um funcionário já trabalhou, porém as formas que tentei apresentaram valores incorretos. Seguem as mesmas abaixo:

Esta retorna a diferença com 3 horas e 2 minutos a menos:

```
$horario1 = '16:05:00';
$horario2 = '10:16:53';   
date('H:i:s',(strtotime($horario1) - strtotime($horario2))));
```

E esta retornou 21:00:06 para os horário acima exemplificados:

```
date('H:i:s',($horario1 - $horario2)));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fiz dessa forma e funcionou corretamente:

```
//Calcula o tempo de upload
$entrada = $horario1;
$saida = $horario2;
$hora1 = explode(":",$entrada);
$hora2 = explode(":",$saida);
$acumulador1 = ($hora1[0] * 3600) + ($hora1[1] * 60) + $hora1[2];
$acumulador2 = ($hora2[0] * 3600) + ($hora2[1] * 60) + $hora2[2];
$resultado = $acumulador2 - $acumulador1;
$hora_ponto = floor($resultado / 3600);
$resultado = $resultado - ($hora_ponto * 3600);
$min_ponto = floor($resultado / 60);
$resultado = $resultado - ($min_ponto * 60);
$secs_ponto = $resultado;
//Grava na variável resultado final
$tempo = $hora_ponto.":".$min_ponto.":".$secs_ponto;
echo $tempo;
```

Comment: Funcionou corretamente. Você poderia me explicar o porque da multiplicação e  divisão por 3600 e por 60?

Comment: 3600 transforma segundos em horas e vice versa. 60 minutos para segundos.

Comment: Eu acho legal como didática, mas na prática o PHP já tem funções mais simples e prontas para resolver o problema. `strtotime( '1970-01-01 '.$horario1 )` já retorna o valor em segundos.

Comment: Agora, se for um caso em que a hora, minuto e segundo já estão separados, definitivamente eu também acho melhor usar matemática do que a interpretação textual do `strtotime`. De qq forma, +1

Comment: Outro jeito interessante de obter os segundos totais tendo horas e minutos separados, é esse: `mktime ($hora,$minuto,$segundo,1,1,1970)`

Comment: @Bacco, tens razão. Mas quebrei muito a cabeça e foi essa solução matemática que melhor solucionou meu caso. Obrigado pelas considerações.