# Retornar diferença de horas e minutos com PHP

Tags: php, data

Tenho este arquivo simples:

*teste.php*

```
  <?php

  $date1='2018-01-09 16:14:01';
  $date2='2018-01-09 17:30:04';

  $dateS1 = new \DateTime($date1);
  $dateS2 = new \DateTime($date2);

  $dateDiff = $dateS1->diff($dateS2);
  $result = $dateDiff->h . ' horas e ' . $dateDiff->i . ' minutos';
  echo $result;
  ?>
```

Em teoria deveria me retornar a diferença em horas e minutos, porém, me volta apenas um página em branco.

Vcs acham que pode ser a versão do PHP na minha maquina? Uso a versão 5.1.6

Comment: este código está certo, foi testado e funciona normalmente, se poder postar o erro que aparece,

Comment: Esse é o problema kkk, não retorna nada, apenas uma pagina em branco

Comment: Aqui funcionou perfeitamente. Os dois arquivos estão na mesma pasta? o arquivo funcoes.php tem as tags <?php e ?>?

Comment: Poderia passar todo o conteúdo do funcoes.php?

Comment: @RafaelWeber, sim todos os arquivos estão em uma unica pasta, e tb estão com as tags, vou editar a pergunta com o código em um único arquivo para facilitar, pois tente junto e tb não funcionou

Comment: não há erros, vide http://kithomepage.com/sos/paginainclud.php

Comment: Segundo a Documentação do PHP a versão deve ser superior ou igual a 5.3 http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.diff.php

Comment: @RafaelWeber, puts, então é isso :(, tô no servidor da empresa, existe outra forma de fazer esse calculo de diferença?

Comment: rodei este código na versao 5.1.6 do php e ele deu fatal error, classe date time nao encontrada

Comment: Faça teste nesse site, tem todas as versões de php para testar , esse é com versão 5.3  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6e4b72504cc1454f009e4acaf17c912ace3ded25

Comment: E esse é com a sua versão 5.1.6  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8a71b4c79f70e95507984388c01624e563a52c70

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Segundo a Documentação do PHP a versão deve ser superior ou igual a 5.3

[PHP DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.diff.php)

Para sua versão encontrei uma [Pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127231/calcular-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-horas-no-php) já respondida que pode lhe ajudar.

Comment: Mas esse método só funciona com horas, preciso de um que conte os dias tb :(

Answer (score 2):

Repliquei seu código nesse [site](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/) que contem o servidor do php com a `5.1.6` e o mesmo apresenta um `fatal error pois a classe nao está definida.`

e como ja foi dito na documentação do php a classe [datetime.diff](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.diff.php) é valida para php `5.3` ou superior

Comment: Fiz isso cara, mas não funfou tb, e eu uso outras funções com parenteses e isso nunca deu problema :(

Comment: cara repliquei seus códigos em um ambiente de teste e colocando a recomendação da tag php no arquivo funcoes.php nao apresenta nenhum erro, caso o problema nao seja este é algo que você precisa acrescentar na pergunta, que voce nao acrescentou

Comment: @Shinchila_Matadora o que eu poderia complementar para que a resposta seja dada como aceita ?

Comment: O problema está tão somente na versão utilizada, veja que a pergunta foi editada e não tem mais o include e mesmo assim apresenta erro devido a versão

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo valeu :D

Answer (score 2):

Conforme já responderam, a classe [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.datetime.php) está disponível nas versões `PHP 5 >= 5.2.0 e PHP 7`.

O que você pode fazer pra contornar é:

```
$data1 = '2018-01-09 16:14:01';
$data2 = '2018-01-09 17:30:04';

$unix_data1 = strtotime($data1);
$unix_data2 = strtotime($data2);

$nHoras   = ($unix_data2 - $unix_data1) / 3600;
$nMinutos = (($unix_data2 - $unix_data1) % 3600) / 60;

printf('%02d:%02d', $nHoras, $nMinutos); // 01:16
```

Exemplo no [ideone](https://ideone.com/nYs40G)

Comment: E se eu quisesse calcular a diferença de dias, mês ou ano?

Comment: E como eu salvo isso no banco como uma string, no caso o resultado 01:16?