# Calcular média de tempo de atendimento

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Galera, estou precisando tirar a média de tempo de atendimentos e tenho os seguintes dados:

```
00:12:35
00:05:10
00:01:42
00:08:12
00:01:01
{...}
```

A pergunta é, como que posso fazer? Pesquisei uma maneira de fazer isso usando AVG do Mysql mas não tive sucesso... Tentei somar e dividir pela quantidade de registros mas o numero ficou quebrado... Alguém já passou por algo parecido?

Agradeço antecipadamente pela ajuda!

Comment: dê uma olhada neste link  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127231/calcular-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-horas-no-php

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Calcular diferença entre horas no php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127231/calcular-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-horas-no-php)

Comment: O comentário acima resolve seu problema. Já que ensina retirar a diferença entre horas e o tempo médio do atendimento é a soma das diferenças dividida pela quantidade de atendimentos.

Answer (score 1):

Faça a média com valores inteiros convertendo os tempos para segundos e depois convertendo para tipo tempo novamente:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(`tempo_atendimento`)))
```